# How to deploy AWS Lambdas with Docker and CDK?

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

#### Context

I'm able to deploy to AWS lambda using Docker and CDK.

Here is what I did:

I have a Java package `TestLambda`. I use `docker build -t test-lambda .` there to build the docker image.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/java:11

# /var/task should only contains *.class files
#COPY build/classes/java/main ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Always use /var/task/lib for dependencies
COPY build/dependency/* ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/lib/

COPY src/main/resources/log4j2.xml ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

ARG jarFile=TestLambda-0.0.1.jar

# Looks
COPY build/libs/${jarFile} ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/lib/

RUN cd ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT} && jar -xf ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/lib/${jarFile}

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "com.mywebsite.TestLambda::handle" ]
```

I have a CDK package where I defined Lambda Stack:

```js
export interface LambdaStackProps extends cdk.StackProps {
  readonly env : cdk.Environment
}

export class LambdaStack extends cdk.Stack {

  // Make it public so that can be binded to Api Gateway
  public readonly testLambda : lambda.Function;

  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props: LambdaStackProps) {
      super(scope, id, props);

      this.testLambda = this.createLambda();
  }


  private createLambda() {
      // Configure path to Dockerfile
      const dockerfile = path.join(__dirname, "../../TestLambda/");

      // Because here it uses Asset,
      // need run cdk bootstrap aws://<AwsAccountId>/us-east-1
      return new lambda.DockerImageFunction(this, 'TestLambdaHandler', {
          functionName: 'TestLambdaHandler',
          description: 'Lambda that render presigned url for S3 bucket.',
          code: lambda.DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset(dockerfile),
          timeout: cdk.Duration.minutes(2),
          memorySize: 512,
          role: this.createLambdaExecutionRole(),
          tracing: lambda.Tracing.ACTIVE,
      });
  }

  private createLambdaExecutionRole() {
    return new iam.Role(this, "TestLambdaHandlerRole", {
      description: "Execution role for TestLambdaHandler.",
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
      inlinePolicies: {
        "TestLambdaHandlerRoleInlinePolicies" : new iam.PolicyDocument(
          {
            statements : [
              new iam.PolicyStatement({
                effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
                resources: ["*"],
                actions: [
                  "s3:Create*",
                  "s3:List*",
                  "s3:Set*",
                  "s3:Put*",
                  "s3:Get*",
                ]
              }),
              new iam.PolicyStatement({
                effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
                resources: ["*"],
                actions: [
                  "logs:Get*", "logs:Describe*", "logs:Create*", "logs:Put*"
                ]
              })
            ]
          }
        )
      }
    });
  }
}
```

With the above code, I'm able to upload the docker image and deploy to AWS Lambda with command`cdk deploy LambdaStack`.

#### My question

Above code works for one Java Lambda function. And now I want add more Java functions to my Java package, and use the CDK package to deploy the docker image as a whole.

How can I do that?

As you can see in my Dockerfile, there is a line `CMD [ "com.mywebsite.TestLambda::handle" ]` specified the function that should be run, and Dockerfile can only have one CMD.

I tried to add another CMD for my new function and make the Dockerfile looks like:

```
CMD [ "com.mywebsite.GetS3PresignedUrl::handleRequest" ]
CMD [ "com.mywebsite.activity.Test::handleRequest" ]
```

Of course, I also updated the TypeScript CDK package to add corresponding code for the second lambda function. Basically a copy of my above code.

After deployment, I see two AWS lambda functions. But both lambda functions call `com.mywebsite.activity.Test::handleRequest`. As mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/), "If you list more than one `CMD` then only the last `CMD` will take effect."

I want the single docker image to hold all my Lambda functions, how can I do that?

#### Update 2021-11-22

With @gshpychka's help, I'm able to get this working.

Paste the CDK code for one lambda here. Other lambda configurations should be the same.

```js
private createTestLambda() {
      const dockerfile = path.join(__dirname, "../../MyLambda/");
      const myCode = lambda.Code.fromAssetImage(dockerfile, {
        cmd: ['com.mywebsite.TestActivityWrapper::handleRequest'],
      });
      return new lambda.Function(this, 'TestLambda', {
          functionName: 'TestLambda',
          description: 'Test lambda',
          code: myCode,
          handler: lambda.Handler.FROM_IMAGE,
          runtime: lambda.Runtime.FROM_IMAGE,
          timeout: cdk.Duration.minutes(2),
          memorySize: 512,
          role: this.createTestLambdaExecutionRole(),
          tracing: lambda.Tracing.ACTIVE,
      });
  }

  private createTestLambdaExecutionRole() {
    return new iam.Role(this, "TestLambdaRole", {
      description: "Execution role for TestLambdaRole.",
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
      inlinePolicies: {
        "TestLambdaRoleRoleInlinePolicies" : new iam.PolicyDocument(
          {
            statements : [
              new iam.PolicyStatement({
                effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
                resources: ["*"],
                actions: [
                  "s3:Create*",
                  "s3:List*",
                  "s3:Set*",
                  "s3:Put*",
                  "s3:Get*",
                ]
              }),
              new iam.PolicyStatement({
                effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
                resources: ["*"],
                actions: [
                  "logs:Get*", "logs:Describe*", "logs:Create*", "logs:Put*"
                ]
              })
            ]
          }
        )
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean having a single docker image that holds all your lambda functions which you then distinguish using the Handler attribute?

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. Please be more specific.

Comment: @stijndepestel yes. exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `lambda.Function` construct insead. It allows you to reuse a docker asset and override the handler. Remove the `CMD` entries from the Dockerfile.

```js
  const my_code = lambda.Code.fromAssetImage(dockerfile);
  const my_lambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'TestLambdaHandler', {
      functionName: 'TestLambdaHandler',
      description: 'Lambda that render presigned url for S3 bucket.',
      code: my_code,
      handler: 'com.mywebsite.activity.Test::handleRequest',
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.FROM_IMAGE,
      timeout: cdk.Duration.minutes(2),
      memorySize: 512,
      role: this.createLambdaExecutionRole(),
      tracing: lambda.Tracing.ACTIVE,
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I changed as you advised here. But encounter error: Type 'DockerImageCode' is not assignable to type 'Code'. It seems that lambda.DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset(dockerfile) return a type `DockerImageCode` which is not compatible with the `Code` type. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You're right, that was an error on my part. Updated the question to use `Code`.